# Shallow clone at a git hash tag

Tags: git, git-clone

I'd like to do a shallow clone of a large repository to reduce the download time. I don't actually need any history or git metadata for this use case. I just need the files in the repository at a specific commit hashtag. Using `--depth 1 --branch <name>` works for the tip of a branch or a tag, but doesn't allow a raw commit hashtag. I saw one workaround where a clone was made with `--depth 50` and followed by a `git checkout` at the desired hashtag. The desired hashtag was always within 50 from the tip, but in my use case, I can't guarantee any fixed distance without defeating the purpose of the shallow clone. Is there another approach to doing this or a configuration option I missed?

Comment: I have the same issue, did not yet see a clear solution for this. Any updates?

Answer (score 0):

I would step back and look at my development process. It is -- unsettling -- that depth=50 does not get you to the commit that you need. This sounds like code that needs some refactoring to break out the functionality that you need to modify. 51+ commits back sounds like a nightmare merge waiting to happen (unless your use case precludes merging your changes, which again sounds like a break-apart-and-refactor scenario).

Comment: This isn't for editing code. This is just to get a snapshot of the current tree at a point in time. The --depth=50 example is from the travis-ci build servers. They can assume that when a build is triggered that the hashtag to test will be near the tip of the branch. Using a depth > 1 would be needed to avoid a race condition. In my case, I'd rather not rely on a hardcoded distance.